# Express-session is not setting cookie data in safari browsers

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

Why does express-session ***is not setting cookie*** on **HTTP** websites in safari browsers? It is working fine in chrome and all other browsers even if the web site is **http web site**. It is getting fail to set cookie for safari browsers. What went wrong in my code? Any suggestions?

I have set up my code like below

```
app.use(session({
  genid: (req) => {
    return uuid() // use UUIDs for session IDs
  },
  secret: 'some secret',
  resave: false,
  cookie:{maxAge:60000*30,secure:false,httpOnly:false},
  name : 'myweb-site-session-id',
  saveUninitialized: true
}))
```

// Add headers

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```